# What is the full form of PAR in terms of IEEE documents?

Tags: 802.11

Every IEEE standard has a PAR document, like I found CSD to be Criteria for Standards Development. PAR is a similar document which is approved before working on a standard. Apologies if the question is not fit for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "what is the full form?" means "what does the acronym stand for?"...  Project Authorization Request (PAR)  https://standards.ieee.org/develop/par.html